# How to align the bottom of a figure to axis label in R using the patchwork package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am trying to patch two plots using patchwork in R.

Currently, my figure looks like this: [image]

The 2 plots are generated with ggplot2 and saved in two variables, pl1 and pl2.
The patchwork snipped used is:

```
pl1 + pl2 + plot_layout(widths = c(5, 3)) + plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
```

Any ideas on how I can extend the figure B to match the bottom of figure A?

I'd like the bottommost node in the network to be aligned with the "Relation on Wikidata" snippet.

The full code is available at https://github.com/lubianat/cellosaurus_paper/blob/master/src/fig2.R but I could try and provide a simpler code, if the issue is somehow unclear.

Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: The easiest solution to a different question is to swap the x and y coordinates of the first plot, so your labels can be read horizontally and you don't have this huge margin for the placement of axis text that conflicts with the alignment of the second plot..

Comment: That is a good suggestion! I will use it as a backup if it is too complicated, thanks.